# In C# and VS2012, How do I find all lines that make use of a particular "using" directive?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, using-directives

I wish I could find a better way to word the title, but hopefully it becomes more clear as I explain. I'm also hoping that Visual Studio supports what I'd like to use it for, or that someone is aware of a plug-in or slick workaround that will answer my question.

**Really simple example:**

```
using System.IO
public class MyClass
{
    if (File.Exists("myfile.txt"))
    {
        //Do something that doesn't involve System.IO
    }
}
```

I want to point at a particular using (like System.IO) and find every line that relies on the using directive, such as the "File.Exists" line.

In VS2012 you can right-click the "using" directives at the beginning of a file and select Organize Usings > Remove Unused Usings. This is great, but I want to sort of do the reverse of that.

**A solution that is clumsy and time consuming.**
One method would be to erase a using line, and attempt to build, and then look through all the errors to try and find the appropriate ones. This answer feels like a hack, takes time, and produces the result as a list of errors.

**The Circumstance.**
I'm refactoring a bunch of code. One of the classes has over 4000 lines of code and 13 using directives. In looking at the in house references, I can tell that this 800lbs gorilla class is referencing namespaces from very different parts of the system. I want to identify the areas of the code that make use of a particular using in order to help me segment this class up. Simply compiling with a missing using takes time and doesn't produce the results in a helpful format.

To try and phrase the question another way:
"How do I get visual studio to show me all the lines of code that rely on a particular using directive?"

Comment: It doesn't as far as I can remember. The refactoring capabilities of vanilla VS2012 just wasn't there.  It would be easier to write some analyzers instead and possibly code fixes to go along with it to automate the process.

Comment: You can have a dependency on another part of the system using fully-qualified names also, then no using directive is implicated.  I would forget about using directives and try to identify usages.  Have you tried NDepend?  It's been a while since I used it, but IIRC measuring coupling between components is exactly what it does best.

Comment: I suggest using http://www.ndepend.com/.

Comment: I would actually choose the solution that is clumsy and time consuming: replace the using line with //using System.IO with comments and then build the solution to get the list of errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the using statement then click on "Find All References" from the drop-down menu.

Comment: That doesn't quite do it. First, it only returns results that specify the namespace in the method call. So it'll find _if (System.IO.File.Exists("myfile.txt"))_ but it won't find _if (File.Exists("myfile.txt"))_. It also searches the entire project, and not the one file/class.

Comment: I see. What exactly are you going to do with all those using directives after you found them?

Comment: Us it as a sort of guidance for how to break the 4000 line class up. The real example using in house library names wouldn't mean much, but imagine you had a giant class that was making calls to Libraries used for "UI Display", "Database Access". If you say found 1000 lines of that code was making calls to the database, you might suspect that it's a good candidate for moving to it's own class.

Comment: I can suggest to try 2 more things: 1) if you are using Visual Studio 2012 or 2013, you can highlight that particular using directive or any other word your code, All the other places where that same word is used will be highlighted in you code so you can see them more easily. 2) You can press CTRL+F, then, an search dialog will be shown. Check replace with checkbox, type the word that you are looking for in the search field, type /*found you*/ in replace field, and all the parts of the code where that word was used will be replaced with /*found you*/ comment.